# lxde "run" (alt+F2) doesn't have autocompletion

Tags: launcher, lxde

I have ubuntu 12.04, with lxde.

The screenshot below is taken from LXDE site. It shows the recently-launched items. In my computer, however, there's no autocomplete drop-down.

In addition, i'd  like the box to show me already the last command, and start autocompletion from 1st character typed in.

[image]

How do I enable autocompletion?

Alternatively, Is there another launcher for ubuntu with autocompletion and maybe even more options, that I can hook to Alt-F2 ?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative launcher can be installed like gmrun

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmrun/

```
sudo apt-get install gmrun
```

Update the keyboard shortcut in `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`

```
<keybind key="W-r">
    <action name="Execute">
         <command>gmrun</command>
    </action>
</keybind>
```